# Only one SAN when issuing certificate using Windows

Tags: windows, certificate, ad-certificate-services

I'm trying to [issue a SAN application using *Certificate Enrollment* in Windows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625722(v=ws.10).aspx). I have an AD CS I'm using.

I'm trying to use the *Computer* certificate template and in **Properties** I've specified multiple SANs. But, when the certificate has been issued, only 1 SAN is left (the first one specified), leaving the certificate unusable.

How do I issue a certificate with multiple SANs?

Comment: Just use another template ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because `Computer` certificate template ignores user-supplied subject and builds the subject automatically based on AD information. You have to use different template where subject is constructed from a user-supplied values, for example, `Web Server` template.